# Three-way binding in knockoutJS? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I wrote this code below, but I can't understand how to bind edited values to the table. So my problem is:

1. When I click on "edit" button, there comes dialog window and shows
   me values from the table in dialog's inputs.
2. I edit the values.
3. I click on accept button
4. My new(edited) values saves in localStorage and in output below the table(h3 text), but they don't change the values in the table,
   before you reload the page

So, my question is: why doesn't my code replace values in the table without reloading the page?

```
book.name = self.editor.name();
book.author = self.editor.author();
book.genre = self.editor.genre();
```

Full code snippet:

```
var books = [
    {
        id : 1,
        name : "Javascript",
        author : "David Flanagan",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "100"
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "PHP",
        author : "Luke Welling",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "120"
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        name : "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",
        author : "Addy Osmani",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "400"
    },
    {
        id : 4,
        name : "Understanding ECMAScript 6",
        author : "Nicholas C. Zakas",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "204"
    },
    {
        id : 5,
        name : "Programming JavaScript Applications",
        author : "Eric Elliot",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "214"
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name : "The C Programming Language",
        author : "Brian W. Kernighan",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "514"
    },
    {
        id : 7,
        name : "Programming Pearls",
        author : "Jon L. Bentley",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "114"
    },
    {
        id : 8,
        name : "Java Concurrency in Practice",
        author : "Brian Goetz",
        genre : "learning",
        price : "140"
    }
];
var idNumber;
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    idNumber = books.length
}
function Book(id, name, author, genre) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.author = ko.observable(author);
    this.genre = ko.observable(genre);
}
var bookModel = function (books) {
    var self = this;
    var rowId;
    self.books = ko.observableArray(books);

    self.total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.books().length; i++) {
            total = total + +self.books()[i].price;
        }
        return total.toFixed(2);
    });

    self.addBook = function () {
        idNumber += 1;
        console.log(idNumber);
        self.books.push({
            id: idNumber,
            name: '',
            author: '',
            genre: '',
            price: ''
        });

    };

    self.removeBook = function (book) {
        self.books.remove(book);
        rowId = book.name;
        console.log(rowId);
        updateLocalStorage();
    };

    self.editor = new Book();

    //self.editBook = function (book) {
    self.editItem = function (book) {
        // populate editor values
        self.editor.id(book.id);
        self.editor.name(book.name);
        self.editor.author(book.author);
        self.editor.genre(book.genre);

        // create dialog
        $('#editDisplay').dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 400,
            buttons: {
                Accept: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    book.name = self.editor.name();
                    book.author = self.editor.author();
                    book.genre = self.editor.genre();

                    console.log(book);
                    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(books));
                    $('#outputName').text(book.name)
                    $('#outputAuthor').text(book.author)

                    //location.reload()
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    };

    //};


    function updateLocalStorage() {
        var localBook = JSON.parse(localStorage['table']);
        for (var i = 0; i < localBook.length; i++) {
            if (localBook[i].name == rowId) {
                localBook.splice(i, 1);
                localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(localBook));
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    self.save = function () {
        localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(books));
    };
};


if (localStorage['table'] == '[]') {
    localStorage.clear();
}

if (localStorage['table'] !== undefined) {
    var local = JSON.parse(localStorage['table']);
    var viewModel = new bookModel(local);

}
else {
    var viewModel = new bookModel(books);
    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(self.books));
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[And my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpnTU/719/)

Comment: You may also want to move some more relevant code here, I would suggest the whole js snippet. The jsfiddle link may break. It should only be an addition to the question.

Comment: @Olga Yes, I tried to use codesnippet, but had problems with adding some scripts. But thank you for the advice, I will use it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`book.name` is not an observable when you first create your `viewModel` by instantiating `bookModel`.

See you pass an array with static objects (by that I mean that their properties are not observable):

`self.books = ko.observableArray(books);`

So when you apply bindings the `tds` are bound to static values.

What you could try is construct books with observable properties using your `Book` constructor. E.g.

```
self.books = ko.observableArray(books.map(function (book) {
    return new Book(book);
}));
```

Then after editing the book you will be able to update book's observable properties like so:

```
book.name(self.editor.name());
book.author(self.editor.author());
book.genre(self.editor.genre());
```

That is the idea, of course you need to carefully implement it.

Comment: Thank you a lot ) Will you be so kind to see why I can't save in localStorage my result, after I used your code. http://jsfiddle.net/WpnTU/721/

Comment: Lets start with a few questions - is save function called? If so what is it writing to localStorage? If you are stringifying `book` with observable properties you may get an unexpected result. I will be able to take a closer look in a couple of hours.

Comment: 1. Inside `self.editItem` function we have `accept`(button) function, which writes data to localStorage(it's similar to `save` button on the page) 2. I am trying to stringify `books` (it is a `bookModel` function's parametr: `var bookModel = function (books)`) which gives us an array of objects. But these objects don't take new values, after editing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Everything you are saying is correct. You are trying to save the same `books` that you originally passed to constructor. But they are not changed in your script. Let's call `books` - `model`, `self.books` - is then our `viewModel`. `self.books` is changing - as you can see in table. What you should do is save `self.books` instead. But be carefull - observables are functions and `JSON.stringfigy` will ignore them completely. When you use `map` method you are creating a copy of array, that is one reason `books` is not changing. Tell me if you need more explanation.

Comment: Now I have understood my problem... But when I try to  save `self.books` I receive function, instead of values. If I save `self.books()` I will receive array of objects, which properties are functions. (here is my screen http://take.ms/xmW6H ) As far as I understood I need to create a copy of this `self.books()` array and take somehow values of this property functions... Am I wright?  Sorry for my question, but how can we make this?